# The play-services-ads API has changed (again)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've just updated the play-services-ads dependency from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
```

and now the ad doesn't work anymore. In fact, it doesn't compile. This is what I have:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PublisherAdView ad = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    PublisherAdRequest adRq = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
    ad.loadAd(adRq);
```

The `doubleclick` package doesn't exist anymore; and thus neither do `PublisherAdView` and `PublisherAdRequest`. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) shows an `AdView` instead of a `PublisherAdView`. I remember vaguely that I had to deal with this before, and if I remember correctly it was an `AdView` before I had to change it to `PublisherAdView`.

Is the reason known why google keeps changing the API back and forth?

Comment: If you have questions about the update, I assume you already read the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/migration) linked to from the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/rel-notes)? I don't think anyone can speak authoritatively on whether the Google Ads team will ever change their API surface in some unknowable time in the future.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Both links you shared only show 'Service Unavailable'.

Answer (score 3):

The [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration) seems like in your case it's luckily just renames.

Using your example:

- `doubleclick.PublisherAdView` -> `admanager.AdManagerAdView`
- `doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest` -> `admanager.AdManagerAdRequest`

Ultimately, breaking changes with a new major version have to be expected. The [release notes for 20.0.0](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes) even explicitly state this will be a large change (along with all changes made):

> This release is a MAJOR version update with several breaking changes.
> See the [prepare for SDK v20](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration) guide for more information on how to
> migrate.

Comment: Was it an accident to swap request and view classes?

Comment: It was! Fixed, sorry.